# Lock a table on purpose without returning results

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, blocking

In an update script I'm locking several tables.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    SELECT Top 0 Null FROM TableA with (holdlock, tablockx)
    SELECT Top 0 Null FROM TableB with (holdlock, tablockx)
    ...
```

I want to suppress results for it in order to focus on real script results. Is there an elegant way to xlock a table without getting a result set?

[image: empty result in ssms]

Comment: Related: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/290783/1192

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There may be other ways, but this technique seems simple enough:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
BEGIN TRANSACTION
declare @DummyVariable INT
SET @DummyVariable = (SELECT  Top 0 Null FROM Test1 with (holdlock, tablockx))
```

Comment: short and simple. Even shorter is `SELECT @noResult = Null FROM ...`

Comment: The `holdlock` is superfluous. It is equivalent to `serializable`. The exclusive table lock is sufficient on its own.

Comment: I tried testing this and it did not work as expected. It did not prevent updates from a separate connection.  However using the approach below `UPDATE locktest WITH (TABLOCKX) SET id = NULL WHERE 1 = 2;` worked exactly as expected preventing a separate connection from making any updates until the Transaction was released.

Answer (score 9):

You could update some records with a where clause that never matches like this:

Test setup:

```
CREATE TABLE locktest (id int, sometext nvarchar(50));

INSERT INTO locktest (id, sometext) VALUES
(1, 'dqsmfkqdsfjm'),
(2, 'qmsdfmdj'), 
(3, 'qkfjmsdfjk');
```

If you then, in one query window execute this:

```
BEGIN TRAN;
UPDATE locktest WITH (tablockx)  SET id=null WHERE 1=2;
```

You will see that a `SELECT`in another query window is blocked until you execute

```
COMMIT TRAN;
```

This would lock the table without returning a result set.
If you want to suppress the `0 rows affected` message you could add

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
```

If you only want to block updates but let readers still read the table you could use:

```
UPDATE locktest WITH (tablock, updlock)  SET id=null WHERE 1=2;
```

Comment: I think it's misleading if you read `UPDATE` in SQL code in order to acquire an X-lock.

Comment: Excellent idea and works exactly as needed -- to lock a table from updates, but still allow reading from it, without actually modifying it. I tested it and this solution works exactly as described meanwhile the above option using a Variable, unfortunately did not work.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use [`sp_getapplock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-getapplock-transact-sql) but you're forcing serializable concurrency when you do this for exclusive access and it's a terrible idea.

```
sp_getapplock @Resource = 'MyTable', @LockMode = 'Exclusive';
```

However, this will not take an actual lock on the resource and is an application logical lock only. When I read the OPs statement I did not think that actually locking the tables would be a good idea as there is a script or application that is attempting to do something. Since locking the tables will effectively cause serialized access to the tables - or worse, result in deadlocks in the script effectively denying everyone access - I gave this application lock example as a possible alternative. This way the application lock can be checked and/or taken for the parts in the script that were necessary but leaving the system in an otherwise functioning state.

If the OP truly does need to lock tables and provide serialized access, it may be worth changing the isolation level to `serializable` or re-thinking how the script or application functions.

Comment: My script changes database schema and reorganizes data. It runs once per database. Therefore table X-lock is the right way IMHO. But that's another point. My question above was about the result sets. `sp_getapplock` doesn't create any result at least.

Comment: If it changes schemas... that's going to require a schema-modification lock which isn't compatible with any other locks, so I'm not sure why the xlock? @VV5198722